# JFace Tableviewer multiple filters one textbox

Tags: filter, jface, tableviewer

I have problem regarding my Filtering of my Table. I'm using a ViewerFilter and override the select Method to fitler that Table. The Filtertext itself is entered via a Textfield.

So now to my problem. For example my table looks like the following:

```
      column
       123  
       124
```

In my textfield the user can enter the columnname=data1,data2 to show all rows which have either data1 or data2 as data. so in my above example if the user enters column=123,124 both rows should still be visible. The problem here is that I refresh my tableviewer after each entered character. So when the user enters column=123 the Table only shows one column. When adding ,124 to the filtertext I filter my already filtered table. So no data gets shown at the end. How can I still filter the original Tabledata?

```
@Override
public boolean select(final Viewer viewer, final Object parentElement, final Object element) {
    final String filterString = filterText.getText().toLowerCase();
    if (filterString.length() == 0) { return true; }

    final mydata myData= (mydata) element;
    if (filterString.matches("columnName" + ".+")) {
    index = filterString.indexOf("columnName" + ".+");
   evaluateText(myData, filterString, i, index + tableColumnsText[i].length())  
}

public boolean evaluateText(final mydata data, final String filterText, final int beginningIndex) {
        subString = filterText.substring(beginningIndex, filterText.length());
        return evaluateString(data.getString(), subString);
}


public boolean evaluateString(final String cellString, final String commaString) {
    int countSubstrings = 0;
    final String[] items = commaString.split(",");
    countSubstrings = items.length;

    for (final String s : items) {
        if (s.length() != 0) {
            if (!cellString.contains(s)) { return false; }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So I tried to filter out the main components of the method. Can I somehow access the unfiltered table?